# Failing to authenticate to redis with Airflow Celery worker

Tags: redis, celery, airflow

I am trying to run Airflow Celery worker with redis backend but cant get the connection between the worker and redis to work.

Here is how the configuration looks like:

```
broker_url = redis://:<my-password>@localhost:6379/0
```

I am getting error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'my-password-string'
```

Anyone know any fix for this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Celery beat + redis with password throws No Auth exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49376540/celery-beat-redis-with-password-throws-no-auth-exception)

Answer (score 1):

That's because there're special characters in your password, you can simply do this:
e.g. your password is `my#pw#`

1. do [url-encoding](https://www.urlencoder.org/), then you get `my%23pw%23`
2. append another `%` before `%` to allow airflow read the config successfully

then the final password is `my%%23pw%%23`, so e.g. the redis broker url in airflow.cfg should be like this:

`broker_url = redis://:my%%23pw%%23@redis-host:6379/0`

Answer (score 0):

So i solved it now.

My password was generated from random characters piped through base64 and it was causing problems.

I changed my password to bit shorter and simplier one and `airflow worker` now runs normally.